# The determinants of upper triangular matrices (For any 2x2 and 3x3 matrix)

Tags: matrices, determinant

I am trying hard to figure out what am I supposed to do, if I am supposed to go on write a conjecture about the particular question. How can I go on about to prove it?

Comment: How would you normally compute the determinant?  Are there particularly good choices for the columns for expanding in minors?

Comment: ad-bc=DetA, where A= [a b] 
                     [c d]

Comment: Which of those is zero in an upper triangular matrix?

Comment: c only I think.

Comment: Define upper triangular matrix.  You seem a little confused about it here and below.

Comment: The numbers below the main diagonal will be zero. I am a bit confused with few mathematical words, since I don't go maths in English.

Comment: Have you written down an upper triangular $3\times3$ matrix (with the zeroes in their places) and thought about how you would compute its determinant by expansion in minors?

Comment: Yes I did, but silly me i didn't notice any pattern, until the below person pointed out and then it hit me, it was a silly question to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write out formula for determinant of 2x2 and 3x3 matrix. Then put elements under the diagonal to zero. What do you get? The determinant is the product of the elements on the diagonal.

For 2x2 case, this means following:

$$
        \begin{vmatrix}
        a & b \\
        c & d \\
        \end{vmatrix} = ad - bc
$$

In upper triangular matrix, $c=0$. Thus the determinant is equal to $ad$.

You can use induction on the dimension of the matrix and expansion by the first column to prove this result for any square matrix.

Comment: I don't get it. What do you mean by putting elements under the diagonal to zero? I am interested in writing out a conjecture about it for any 2x2 and 3x3 matrix. So I would have to give algebraic proof alongside the numerical proof, to solidify it and make a concrete conjecture.

Comment: I am trying to write any numerically and algebraically supported conjecture about the determinant of upper triangular matrices.

Comment: Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: yes for a 2x2 and what about a 3x3?

Comment: For 3x3 matrix, the steps are very similar. First, write down the formula for the determinant. In the next step, put elements under diagonal to zero. 

Alternatively, you can prove this for any nxn matrix by means of mathematical induction. In the nxn case, just expand the matrix into minors by the first column as Eric suggested.

Comment: So in the end my conjecture would be that for any 3x3 upper triangular matrix the determinant will be adi. Correct?
I didn't get what he meant by "expanding the matrix into minors".

Comment: If by i you mean the element in the bottom right corner then yes. It will be the product of elements on the diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling this is homework, so I'm going to see if I can help sketch an argument.

Since this matrix is upper triangular, and you can take the determinant along any row, just choose the bottom row. Now the determinant in the two by two case is just the product of the element in $(2,2)$, times the resulting 1x1 matrix, which is just a scalar, so it's $a_{22}a_{11}$. But both of these elements are on the diagonal, so you might suspect that the determinant of an upper triangular matri x

Using similar reasoning, you can find that that this is true for all upper triangular matrices of any size, using mathematical induction, since the cofactor expansion reduces the problem of a determinant of an $n$ x $n$ matrix to an $(n-1)$ x $(n-1)$ matrix. I'm not so good at formatting, but you can consider that for a 3x3 matrix, you'd have the $(3,3)$ element times the determinant of the resulting 2x2 matrix, which is also upper triangular. See if you can fill in the rest of the details.